# K8S Ingress controller without LoadBalancer

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Good afternoon, colleagues. I am new to kubernetes.
I have a cluster not in the cloud.
I suffer,I cannot make ingress work.
Can I get it to work without LoadBalancer in Cloud?

```
helm install ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --generate-name -n dev




$ kubectl get ingress -A
NAMESPACE              NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                     ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
default                ingress-ireg      <none>   ingress.example.com                 80, 443   6d5h
default                minimal-ingress   <none>   *                                   80        67m
dev                    test-ingress      <none>   test.cluster.local                  80        138m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-kuber   <none>   dashboard.cluster.local             80, 443   5h47m`
```

Does not receive IP, and no access.
Maybe | can throw access through NodeIP to the Ingress controller?

Service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

ingress:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress    $ kubectl get ingress -A
NAMESPACE              NAME              CLASS    HOSTS                     ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
default                ingress-ireg      <none>   ingress.example.com                 80, 443   6d5h
default                minimal-ingress   <none>   *                                   80        67m
dev                    test-ingress      <none>   test.cluster.local                  80        138m
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-kuber   <none>   dashboard.cluster.local             80, 443   5h47m`
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.cluster.local
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /



    $ kubectl get svc -n dev 
    NAME                                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
    hello-service                                   ClusterIP      10.233.45.159   <none>        80/TCP                       167m
    ingress-nginx-1631195942-controller             LoadBalancer   10.233.43.236   <pending>     80:30731/TCP,443:32413/TCP   4m15s
    ingress-nginx-1631195942-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.233.2.62     <none>        443/TCP                      4m15

test.cluster.local = IP address of one of the Node



$ curl -I http://test.cluster.local:30731/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 14:04:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 146
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -I http://test.cluster.local:30731/healthz
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 14:05:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Use NodePort to IngressController

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service3
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: https


$ kubectl get svc -n dev  NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE hello-service                                   ClusterIP     
10.233.45.159   <none>        80/TCP                       176m ingress-nginx-1631195942-controller             LoadBalancer  
10.233.43.236   <pending>     80:30731/TCP,443:32413/TCP   14m ingress-nginx-1631195942-controller-admission   ClusterIP     
10.233.2.62     <none>        443/TCP                      14m my-service3                                     NodePort      
10.233.22.168   <none>        80:30554/TCP,443:32247/TCP   58m



$ curl -I http://test.cluster.local:30731/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 14:16:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 146
Connection: keep-alive

$ curl -I http://test.cluster.local:30731/healthz
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 09 Sep 2021 14:16:01 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: There are different ways to do it. Please refer https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/

Comment: Ansil,  Thank you!